# Find location using Android and keyword search in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, search, keyword

How do I use the [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) API to search the destination by some keywords and get a list of options of destination?

I'm developing an Android application that uses using Google Maps.

Comment: open an map intent with the current location and the destination.

Comment: I found the method "getFromLocationName" don't work very well.can you give me some advice?

Comment: have a look at this, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/26750915/2032561